# How to disable/enable input elements until/before date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a simple form with some input elements, something like this:

```
<form action="..." method="post" id="myform">
<p>Early bird price</p>
<p>
<label for="earlymember">Members: 100 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="earlymember" value="Early bird members, 100 USD">
<label for="earlynotmember">Not members: 120 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="earlynotmember" value="Early bird not members, 120 USD">
</p>
<p>Normal price</p>
<p>
<label for="normalmember">Members: 200 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="normalmember" value="Normal members, 100 USD">
<label for="normalnotmember">Not members: 120 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="normalnotmember" value="Normal not members, 120 USD">
</p>
```

How can I do disable `#normalmember` and `#normalnotmember` radios until a date, for example 2015-09-30 in `jQuery` or simple JavaScript?

(Of course after this date I need to change these radios to enabled and disable the others.)

Comment: maybe use datepicker jquery ui for the dates?

Comment: getDate() on page load and compare it with a predefined date maybe?

Comment: Datepicker? I don't understand you... here is radio buttons...

Comment: dates compare is a good idea... Can you show me an example in answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *highly* recommend you compare the dates on server-side **before** and **after** form submissions because end-users could easily override your client-side code. However, I still provide a client-side solution since you did not mention your server-side environment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myDate = new Date("2015-09-30");
  $('#normalmember,#normalnotmember').prop('disabled', $.now() < myDate.getTime());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="..." method="post" id="myform">
  <p>Early bird price</p>
  <p>
    <label for="earlymember">Members: 100 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="earlymember" value="Early bird members, 100 USD">
    <label for="earlynotmember">Not members: 120 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="earlynotmember" value="Early bird not members, 120 USD">
  </p>
  <p>Normal price</p>
  <p>
    <label for="normalmember">Members: 200 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="normalmember" value="Normal members, 100 USD">
    <label for="normalnotmember">Not members: 120 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="normalnotmember" value="Normal not members, 120 USD">
  </p>
```

Comment: Server-side validation is of course **always required**, just because JS doesn't prevent the user to overcome what you do in JS: if the user desactivates JavaScript in the browser, you need a fallback. And the only and reliable fallback is: server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the current date, and compare it with the date you define:

```js
var date = new Date().getTime();
var compareDate = new Date("2015-09-30");

if (date < compareDate.getTime()) {
  $('#normalmember, #normalnotmember').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="..." method="post" id="myform">
  <p>Early bird price</p>
  <p>
    <label for="earlymember">Members: 100 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="earlymember" value="Early bird members, 100 USD">
    <label for="earlynotmember">Not members: 120 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="earlynotmember" value="Early bird not members, 120 USD">
  </p>
  <p>Normal price</p>
  <p>
    <label for="normalmember">Members: 200 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="normalmember" value="Normal members, 100 USD">
    <label for="normalnotmember">Not members: 120 USD</label>
    <input type="radio" id="normalnotmember" value="Normal not members, 120 USD">
  </p>
```